# Listview Scroll End Event

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want Listview Scroll End Event that when I have a content then I'll click on that content to load more, then when content will display then bottom should be scrolled.

```
private void ScrollViewEvent_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ScrollY + ScrollViewEvent.Height >= ScrollViewEvent.ContentSize.Height)
                AtEnd = true;
            else
                AtEnd = false;
        }

        public bool AtEnd
        {
            get
            {
                return m_atEnd;
            }

            set
            {
                if(m_atEnd != value)
                {
                    m_atEnd = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("AtEnd");

                }
            }
        }

 <ScrollView x:Name="ScrollViewEvent"
                        Scrolled="ScrollViewEvent_Scrolled"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
</ScrollView>
```

On content load the bottom part should be scrolled automatically. I don't have to scroll it.

Answer (score 0):

For this you will have to write Custom Renderer. I had implemented the same in one of my Apps.
For iOS you need to implement `DecelerationEnded` Event of `UITableViewDelegate`.
I am not sure for Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lis[tView.ScrollTo Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.scrollto?view=xamarin-forms) to scroll to the last item for ListView.

```
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="Id" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="First Name" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="Surname" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="Date Of Birth" />
                </Grid>
            </ListView.Header>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Id}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Surname}" />
                            <Label Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Age}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <Button
            x:Name="btn"
            Clicked="Btn_Clicked"
            Text=" Load more items" />
    </StackLayout>


public partial class Page6 : ContentPage
{

    public PersonViewModel p { get; set; }
    public Page6 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        p = new PersonViewModel();
        this.BindingContext = p;

    }      

    private void Btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        personmodel model = p.peoples.Last();
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
      listView.ScrollTo(model, ScrollToPosition.End, true));
    }
}


public class PersonViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<personmodel> peoples { get; set; }


    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        peoples = new ObservableCollection<personmodel>();
      for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
        {
            peoples.Add(new personmodel() { Id="the "+ i +" item",FirstName="cherry",Surname="Bu",Age=28});
        }


    }
}
```